# Audio device (Edirol UA-1000) only showing up as Multichannel Output when I want Stereo option

Tags: 20.04, sound, pulseaudio

This is in Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

i use my Edirol UA-1000 for recording & mixing in Ardour, & all the inputs & outputs work great!

however, for general media use, pulseaudio only gives me a Multichannel Output option, no Stereo- & so when i do a speaker test, the left & rights come thru the appropriate speaker (both front + rear), but the center channel plays through the left speaker, so its always louder on the left. (& the subwoofer channel plays through the right)

I only have two outputs (#1 for left, #2 for right) running out of the Edirol to my speaker setup, and I only ever want stereo as an option but it isn't available. any insight is greatly appreciated! <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a workaround by installing QasHctl and turning all the channels down exept for 1 and 2!!

learned how from this q:
[Ubuntu thinks my Audient iD14 audio interface is Analogue Surround 4.0 when it's actually stereo. Is there any way to fix this?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/714280/ubuntu-thinks-my-audient-id14-audio-interface-is-analogue-surround-4-0-when-its?rq=1)